# How are colors clamped in WebGL (using OES_texture_float)?

Tags: opengl-es, colors, webgl

How are colors clamped in WebGL when using `FLOAT` as color format when rendering into a framebuffer? Can I have color channels below 0.0 and above 1.0? How can I control how colors are clamped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenGL values stored in framebuffers in float format are not clamped, you can store any value (but with a precision that is limited based on the format).

From: https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_color_buffer_float/ 
"NOTE: fragment shaders outputs gl_FragColor and gl_FragData[0] will only be clamped and converted when the color buffer is fixed-point"

If you read these values using a sampler then you should get the value stored in the buffer.

Note: You can verify this by storing values out of this range and then using this data in a shader such that it will be obvious in the output (try filling a float texture with different values covering a large range (e.g. 0-1000) then try rendering this texture to the screen by dividing by 1000, if your data is not clamped you should see the expected values, if it is clamped you will have loss of data.